# If I accidentally knock over a rook with my elbow while reaching for another piece, do I have to move the rook?

Tags: learning, rules, otb-chess

According to the official FIDE rules for otb games, does the above description warrant the touch move rule?

Answer (score 13):

No.

The relevant part in [FIDE's Laws of Chess](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=171&view=article) is Article 4.3 which contains the word *deliberately*.

> 4.3 Except as provided in Article 4.2, if the player having the move
>       deliberately touches on the chessboard:
>
> a. one or more of his own pieces, he must move the first piece touched which can be moved
>
> b. one or more of his opponent’s pieces, he must capture the first piece touched which can be captured
>
> c. one piece of each colour, he must capture the opponent’s piece with his piece or, if this is illegal, move or capture the first
>       piece touched which can be moved or captured. If it is unclear,
>       whether the player’s own piece or his opponent’s was touched first,
>       the player’s own piece shall be considered to have been touched
>       before his opponent’s.

The situation you describe once happened to a team mate of mine. The opponent wanted him to move the touched piece according to the rule, but the arbiter explained it had to be deliberate.

Answer (score -3):

I think the key word is elbow. Unless you were previously moving pieces with your elbow then the touch rule wouldn't apply. Disputes of this kind without a judge can easily be avoided by what we call in my area "you break it you bought it". You can touch a piece as long as you don't lift it from the board.

Comment: No, you are not allowed to touch a piece deliberately without calling for 'Adjust' . If otherwise, it will be considered to be a touch piece move.