# Confusion about Touch and move rule

Tags: rules, tournament

I accidentally touched my bishop and opponent's "Knight", while reaching for my queen during a game, almost simultaneously. Am I forced to take the opponent's piece?

Comment: No, it has to be deliberate. See the answer to this question: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/7657/if-i-accidentally-knock-over-a-rook-with-my-elbow-while-reaching-for-another-pie

Answer (score 5):

FIDE Article 4.3:

> Except as provided in Article 4.2, if the player having the move
>   touches on the chessboard, with the **intention of moving or capturing**:
>
> a. one or more of his own pieces, he must move the first piece touched
>   that can be moved
>
> b. one or more of his opponent’s pieces, he must capture the first
>   piece touched that can be captured
>
> c. one piece of each colour, he must capture the opponent’s piece with
>   his piece or, if this is illegal, move or capture the first piece
>   touched that can be moved or captured. If it is unclear whether the
>   player’s own piece or his opponent’s was touched first, the player’s
>   own piece shall be considered to have been touched before his
>   opponent’s.

If a player touches a piece without the intention of moving or capturing (e.g. fingerslip), there is no touch move restriction.

Comment: I see the language has changed slightly from last year.

Answer (score -3):

No, as long as you say adjust your fine. It has to be deliberate movement in order for touch move to be called upon

Comment: Saying adjust doesn't have anything to do with accidentally touching a piece. You say adjust before you touch a piece to adjust it. You can't know that you are going to touch a piece accidentally and say adjust before that.

Comment: @JiK Well, like bump the piece, then fix it with adjust afterwards.

Comment: @user8213 FIDE and USCF rules (and probably everyone else's) require that the player _announce their intention to adjust a piece **before** touching it._ After it has been touched, the touch-move rule applies regardless of what the player says, though the opponent may decline his right to enforce it.